# Windows SSH asking for passphrase

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I generated a public/private SSH key pair (with no passphrase) using Puttygen on a Windows machine, and copied the public key up to my Linux server. When I use the private key in Putty everything works as expected. However, when I try to ssh from the Windows command line, I get prompted for a passphrase. Since there isn't one, I can't login.

```
ssh -T myserver.com
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\private.ppk':
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Why am I being prompted for a passphrase for a key that doesn't have one?

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631246/ssh-key-passphrase-works-in-windows-but-not-in-linux?rq=1

Comment: The problem is not on the Linux side. The problem is on the Windows side. My key works fine when used through Putty. It asks for the passphrase only when I attempt to SSH via the cmd prompt.

Comment: The command line ssh, is that putty? If its not, it could have the same issue, that is, not recognizing the ppk format.

Comment: See my answer below. The command line SSH was through msysgit, which was incorrectly using Open SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that msysgit was installed to use OpenSSH. Since the kwys were generated in Puttygen, they weren't compatible. I changed the GIT_SSH environment variable to point to Plink.exe, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

And just to mention if anyone uses MINGW in order to ssh he needs to select OPENSSH at puttygen.

If you already have generated a pair with GIT_SSH protocol then go to puttygen and:
Load -> Conversions -> export OpenSSH key